# My program fills memory. Is there another approach?

Tags: python

I know that the object refguess becomes 95^n characters long and that's what's being stored in the memory. Is it possible to load and iterate one element into memory at a time, erasing it before loading a new element? Eventually, I want to port this to run on a GPU to take advantage of the shader cores' superior number crunching ability, so a small RAM footprint would be optimal.

```
import itertools
import string

i = 1
refguess = ''
password = ' ~}}'
charlist = list(string.printable)
charlist = charlist[1:95]

while refguess != password:
    i += 1
    for idx, val in enumerate(list(itertools.product(charlist,repeat=i))):
        refguess = ''.join(map(str,val))
        if refguess == password:
            print('Password is ' + '(' + refguess + ')')
            break
```

Comment: Why do you create a list from the `itertools.product` output? Take that out and it should be fine.

Comment: If I don't, for some reason it spits out the memory address of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as posted by Mark Ransom, was that I was making a list when I didn't have to.

Thank you!